# Tensor product of operators

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

How do I show that:

$(\hat{\sigma} $ $\otimes $ $\langle \Phi|\hat{I} )(\hat{\sigma} $ $\otimes $ $ \hat{I})|\Phi\rangle$           $ =1     $ (The parenthesis many not be strictly correct here)

where:

$\hat{I}$ is the identity operator

I know that $\hat{\sigma}\hat{\sigma}= \hat{I}$ where $\hat{\sigma}=|0\rangle\langle 0|- |1\rangle\langle1|$

$|\Phi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01 \rangle - |10 \rangle)$ , i.e $\langle\Phi |\Phi\rangle =1$

and $|01 \rangle= |0 \rangle \otimes |1\rangle$

The system is in the the hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$

Comment: Please explain your notation and spaces being considered

Comment: Something is wrong with your parenthesizes, at points we are considering the tensor of vectors with operators. Do you want to consider $\langle \Phi| (\sigma\otimes I)(\sigma \otimes I)|\Phi\rangle$? Or maybe I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Gustavo I have done as you suggested

Comment: @Chanler I think I have corrected the parenthesis now

Comment: I tried to make sense of this question as I wrote it down.

For simplicity of notation I removed the hats. First I did $$(\sigma \otimes \langle \phi | \circ I) \circ ( \sigma \otimes I) = (\sigma \circ \sigma) \otimes ( \langle \phi | \circ I \circ I) = I \otimes \langle \phi |$$

Then, it can't apply on $| \phi \rangle$. I think we have a problem of how to interpret the problem.

Comment: Yes, apologies I seem to have made a mistake prior to this step. What would the adjoint of $(\hat{\sigma}\otimes\hat{I})|\Phi\rangle$ be? $\hat{\sigma}\otimes\langle \Phi|\hat{I} $ is obviously wrong. Here $\hat{\sigma}$ is Hermitian.

Answer (score 1):

In light of the comments, I will compute $ \ (\sigma \otimes I) | \phi \rangle$

First note that $$\sigma |0 \rangle = (|0 \rangle \langle 0| - |1 \rangle \langle 1|) |0 \rangle = \langle 0|0 \rangle \cdot |0 \rangle - \langle 1|0 \rangle \cdot |1 \rangle = |0 \rangle$$ and similarly $ \ \sigma |1 \rangle = |1 \rangle$. Then we have

\begin{align*}
(\sigma \otimes I) | \phi \rangle & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big[ (\sigma \otimes I)(|0 \rangle \otimes |1 \rangle) - (\sigma \otimes I)(|1 \rangle \otimes |0 \rangle) \big] = \\ & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( \sigma |0 \rangle \otimes I|1 \rangle - \sigma |1 \rangle \otimes I|0 \rangle) = \\ & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|01 \rangle - |10 \rangle) = \\ & = | \phi \rangle
\end{align*}

You can do now $$\langle \phi | (\sigma \otimes I) | \phi \rangle = \langle \phi |\phi \rangle = 1$$

Comment: $\sigma |1 \rangle = -|1 \rangle$, I believe. I have that $(\sigma \otimes I)| \phi \rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)$

Comment: I understand it is easy to show that if you operate on $(\sigma \otimes I) | \phi \rangle$  with it's adjoint if you use the method you have displayed you get $1$. However unfortunately I have to show this directly. So I need to know a general expression for   $[(\sigma \otimes I) | \phi \rangle]^\dagger$ where $\sigma$ is Hermitian and $\phi \in \mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}$

Comment: Yes, I forgot the minus sign, sorry

Comment: The dual is $$[(\sigma \otimes I)| \phi \rangle]^* = \langle \phi | (\sigma \otimes I)$$

Comment: We have that $$\langle \phi | (\sigma \otimes I) \circ (\sigma \otimes I) | \phi \rangle = 1$$

Comment: Would you be able to explain why  $[(\sigma \otimes I)| \phi \rangle]^* = \langle \phi | (\sigma \otimes I)$? It doesn't appear in my notes.

Comment: I think it is enough to say that $ \ (f \otimes g)^* = f^* \otimes g^* \ $ and the answer for your doubt follows directly.

Comment: \begin{align*}
\langle (f^* \otimes g^*)(a \otimes b) , a \otimes b \rangle & = \langle f^*(a) \otimes g^*(b) , a \otimes b \rangle = \\ & = \langle f^*(a) , a \rangle \cdot \langle g^*(b) , b \rangle = \\ & = \langle a , f(a) \rangle \cdot \langle b , g(b) \rangle = \\ & = \langle a \otimes b , (f \otimes g)(a \otimes b) \rangle
\end{align*}

Comment: I think I understand. One final question why does $\langle \phi|I \otimes I|\phi\rangle=1$?

Comment: I understand we already know that $\langle \phi |\phi \rangle =1$

Comment: Yes, one always has $ \ id_{A \otimes B} = id_A \otimes id_B \ $ for all commutative unital $R$-modules $A$ and $B$. You can prove that directly using the universal property.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your notation here: $ \ id_{A \otimes B} = id_A \otimes id_B \ $?

Comment: For a $R$ module $M$, as usual, I denote $ \ id_M : M \to M \ $ as the identity map $ \ id_M(v)=v$, $\forall v \in M$. It is an isomorphism and self-dual.

Comment: As you can probably tell we've only been introduced to tensor products briefly as part of our quantum mechanics course. I have never heard of duals, the universal property or commutative unital **R** modules. Could you please explain in simpler terms?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37481/discussion-between-gustavo-and-usainlightning).

Comment: No need, I understand it now, many thanks for your help